# Error with Pandas Profiling on Databricks using a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, databricks, azure-databricks

Is someone able to help me understand how to get pandas-profiling working with a dataframe.

using this post ([Unable to run Pandas Profiling on Databricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66005963/unable-to-run-pandas-profiling-on-databricks))i was able to replicate the output using a dictionary, but when using a dataframe, i get the following errors

[image]

i have installed all the libraries with no error, i can view the dataframe with no issues, is this something to do with the storage location? i have read/write access to this location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run Pandas profiler directly on the Spark dataframe - you need to create a Pandas dataframe using the `.toPandas()` function ([doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toPandas.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toPandas)), like this:

```py
profile = ProfileReport(df.toPandas(), title='EDA Report', explorative=True)
```